# C# Return Type should this.getType()

Tags: c#, generics, this

I have a Function in C# and it have to return the type of the Class. Also in subclasses which extends the class.

Like:

```
public class A
{
    public typeof(this) Method()
    {
        //Code
    }
}
public class B : A {

    public override typeof(this) Method() {
        //Code
    }
}
```

So the Method in class A should have the return type A. And the Method in class B should have the return tpye B.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: A.GetType() and B.GetType() are not enough?

Comment: No. You cant take a result of a function as return type.

Comment: `typeof(object)` already exists, and instances of classes have a `GetType()` method inherited from the `object` base already. What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: The return type should be the type of the class.

Comment: I confess I am at a loss here... What do you want to do? Get the type of the class? Get the type of the function returning value?

Comment: But the GetType will do exactly this. Why do ypu need another method to do the same thing???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. What you're asking for is called a covariant return type, but C# doesn't support this. The closest you can get is either this:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual A Method()
    {
        //Code returning an A
    }
}

public class B : A 
{
    public override A Method() 
    {
        //Code returning a B
    }
}
```

Which is legal because every `B` is also an `A`, or you can use generics instead of inheritance:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public virtual T Method()
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

And then you can have `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>` -- however, `Foo` cannot depend on any specifics of `T`. You can combine this with inheritance, which will sort of achieve what you want:

```
public class A : Foo<A> 
{
    // And now A has a Method that returns A
}

public class B : Foo<B> 
{
    // And now B has a Method that returns B
}
```

But the problem with this approach is that you will have a hard time actually *implementing* `Method` in a meaningful way, because in `Foo` you cannot use anything specific to the type. To make this explicit, you could make `Method` abstract:

```
public abstract class Foo<T>
{
    public abstract T Method();
}

public class A : Foo<A> 
{
    public override A Method() 
    {
        // Code
    }
}

public class B : Foo<B> 
{
    public override B Method() 
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time imagining a scenario where you can actually make use of this, but at least it meets the requirements.

Last but not least, you are not *required* to use inheritance -- does `B` really need to derive from `A` or could you inherit from some common base that does not use `Method`?

Comment: But then is in class B the return type A and not B. I want it automatic.

Comment: You can't always get what you want. But if your try sometimes you just might find you get what you need.

Comment: OK. Thats not the best solution. But it is Okay

Comment: @RoboDeBanco: I updated my answer with some more alternatives that may or may not get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your method is trying to do, it might be possible to achieve what you want by using extension methods.

```cs
public class A { }

public class B : A { }

public static class AExtension {
    public static T Method<T>(this T target) where T: A {
        // do your thing here.

        return target; // or, return a new instance of type T.
    }
}
```

You can then call `Method()` and let C# infer the generic argument:

```
var a = new A();
a = a.Method(); // C# will infer T as A.

var b = new B();
b = b.Method(); // C# will infer T as B.
```

The downside to this approach is, of course, that you cannot access non-public members of your classes in `Method()`, unless you use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this, actually.

```cs
class A {
    public A Method () { ... return this; }
}

class B : A {
    new public B Method () => (B)base.Method();
    // or { base.Method(); return this; }
}
```

Make sure you only use this if you know that the base returns `this`.